# How to start writing an autobiography

Tags: publishing, formatting, copyright, structure, self-publishing

I’m planning to write my autobiography. I don’t know where to start. Please give some tips and tricks to kickstart the project. I know it’s my personal stuff. But still some hacks from experienced people may help a lot. I have zero experience. I would like to get suggestions how to create a structure, start curating content, editing and publishing.
Note: I am a blind  writer. Please give some accessible suggestions

Comment: Why not read three or seven or a dozen published biographies and make your own analysis of how they were written?

Comment: Yes, that’s true. I have finished two books till now. I will be reading some more. Still I thought I shall ask for some suggestions from experienced people. And I want to create a to do list for the entire process starting from book draft to the publishing itself. No idea about anything.